# Simple Java Guessing program. Continuing

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, boolean

I am just playing around with java and wanted to make a simple program where the user; me has to guess/type in the correct number until it's correct. What can I do so the program can keep running, printing out "Make another guess" until the user/me puts in the correct number. Maybe a boolean? I'm not sure.  This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class iftothemax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int myInt = 2;

    // Create Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Output the prompt
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");

    //Wait for the user to enter a number
    int value = input.nextInt();

    if(value == myInt) {
        System.out.println("You discover me!");
    }
    else {
        //Tell them to keep guessing
        System.out.println("Not yet! You entered:" + value + " Make another guess");
        input.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: use a while loop, and loop until the value is correct

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use a while loop to repeat some code:

```
while (value != myInt) {
    System.out.println("Not yet! You entered: " + value + ". Make another guess");
    value = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("You discovered me!");
```

Answer (score 1):

This program would do the trick:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int myInt = 2;
    int value = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean guessCorrect = false;
    while(!guessCorrect){
        System.out.println("Not yet! You entered:" + value + " Make another guess");
        value = input.nextInt();
        if(value == myInt){
            guessCorrect = true
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You discover me!");
}
```

Comment: @ParkerHalo, Thanks didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply introduce a loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class iftothemax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myInt = 2;

        // Create Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(;;) {
            //Output the prompt
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");

            //Wait for the user to enter a number
            int value = input.nextInt();


            if(value == myInt) {

                System.out.println("You discover me!");
                break;
            }
            else {
                //Tell them to keep guessing
                System.out.println("Not yet! You entered:" + value + " Make another guess");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @ParkerHalo Why do you think the loop starts too early? I don't know the specification.

Comment: You edited the post accordingly so the loop doesn't start too early now... still i think it's not nice to teach java-newlings things as `for(;;)` and `break` before they know what a loop is!